# whats wrong with this iptable

Tags: iptables

My goal is to allow access to port 11211 (memcache) from mydomain.com by changing the existing iptable.

I used the line:
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s xx.xx.xx.xx --dport 11211 -j ACCEPT
to add the first line in the iptable (xx.xx.xx.xx is the ip of my domain):

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  mydomain.com      anywhere            tcp dpt:11211
ACCEPT     tcp  --  localhost            anywhere            tcp dpt:11211
ACCEPT     tcp  --  domU-12-31-39-01-BC-21.compute-1.internal  anywhere   tcp dpt:11211
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:11211
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www
```

Still when I try to access port 11211 it seems to be blocked (in aws security groups it is open, so thats not the reason)

Whats wrong with this setting ?

Comment: Can you try adding COUNT in the line accepting traffic from mydomain.com, then see if it's incrementing as you try? This would at least verify that your traffic is originating from the place you think it is.

Comment: Also, dumb question, but you do have memcached bound to the external IP, right?

Comment: To see the packet count use `iptables -nvL`.

Comment: In addition to the above, it's not clear from your question if your firewall on the same box as memcache. If it isn't, you need the FORWARD chain, not the INPUT one.

Comment: Did you ever slove this ? If so can you please provide an answer - thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem was but the line 
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 11211 -j ACCEPT
Works for opening the port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem was but the line

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 11211 -j ACCEPT
```

Works for opening the port